# Windows 10 IOT Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twilio, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I am implementing Twilio JS into a UWP application (their JS [here](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js))

The client looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/5c870394c88ec933281e2f3bb17fdeec

At the bottom right is the 'debug window' which shows it got a token, and that Twilio.Device is ready. This works fine on a PC, but on Windows 10 IoT it stops at Got a token. It doesn't show the device is ready. I thought it was a compatibility issue but I checked every box that has to do with this project.

My next though is, that the JavaScript or something isn't implemented on Windows 10 IoT.

It works on the desktop, but on IoT it doesn't get far.

Any help is appreciated.

Update:

I tracked down the error 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Twilio.Exception: twilio.js 1.3 requires WebRTC/ORTC browser support.

Apparently it doesnt support WebRTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone had the same problem. I put the project on hold for a little, but Windows 10 IoT core (as up until this writing), does not have WebRTC or ORTC support.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Client JS is built to support browsers that support WebRTC/ORTC. This means it [is currently compatible with Chrome, Firefox and Edge](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180848-Which-browsers-support-WebRTC-).

The Twilio Client JS has not been built with UWP applications in mind, especially not those running on the IoT build. However, I have just found this [blog post about using WebRTC in UWP applications](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/22/real-time-communications-universal-windows-platform-webrtc-ortc/), perhaps that can help by implementing WebRTC/ORTC within your UWP app.